# Knowing when you've read everything off a multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue

I have some code that farms out work to tasks.  The tasks put their results on a queue, and the main thread reads these results from the queue and deals with them.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool, Manager
import uuid


def handle_task(arg, queue, end_marker):
    ... add some number of results to the queue . . .
    queue.put(end_marker)

def main(tasks):
    manager = Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()
    count = len(tasks)
    end_marker = uuid.uuid4()
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(handle_task, ((task, queue, end_marker) for task in tasks))
        while count > 0:
            value = queue.get()
            if value == end_marker:
                count -= 1
            else:
                ... deal with value ...
```

This code works, but it is incredibly kludgy and inelegant.  What if `tasks` is a iterator?  Why do I need to know how many tasks there are ahead of time and keep track of each of them.

Is there a cleaner way of reading from a Queue and and knowing that every process that will write to that thread is done, and you've read everything that they've written?

Comment: This seems to be an example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you are looking for an improvement to your chosen solution rather than a better solution using a different approach. If you must use an explicit queue for returning results rather than the internal queue implemented by the pool (why?), then I don't see why you don't use a `multiprocessing.Queue`, which has much better performance characteristics. If you do switch, then your methodology is reasonable. But I believe your use of any explicit queue is what complicates your code unnecessarily.

Comment: @Booboo.  I originally used `mp.Queue()` but I got the error message "Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance".  Using a managed queue made the problem go away.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: True, you cannot pass a `multiprocessing.Queue` as an argument to the `map` and `starmap` methods. But you can use the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments to the `Pool` initializer to initialize each pool process with a global variable that is the queue. (See my updated answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, operations on a managed queue are very slow compared to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. But why are you even using an an additional  queue to return results when a multiprocessing pool already uses such a queue for returning results? Instead of having `handle_task` write some number of result values to a queue, it could simply return a list of these values. For example,

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def handle_task(arg):
    results = []
    # Add some number of results to the results list:
    results.append(arg + arg)
    results.append(arg * arg)
    return results

def main(tasks):
    with Pool() as pool:
        map_results = pool.map(handle_task, tasks)
        for results in map_results:
            for value in results:
                # Deal with value:
                print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([7, 2, 3])
```

Prints:

```None
14
49
4
4
6
9
```

As a side benefit, the results returned will be in task-submission order, which one day might be important. If you want to be able to process the returned values as they become available, then you can use `pool.imap` or `pool.imap_unordered` (if you don't care about the order of the returned values, which seems to be the case):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def handle_task(arg):
    results = []
    # Add some number of results to the results list:
    results.append(arg + arg)
    results.append(arg * arg)
    return results

def main(tasks):
    with Pool() as pool:
        for results in pool.imap_unordered(handle_task, tasks):
            for value in results:
                # Deal with value:
                print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([7, 2, 3])
```

If the number of tasks being submitted is "large", then you should probably use the *chunksize* argument of the `imap_unordered` method. A reasonable value would be `len(tasks) / (4 * pool_size)` where you are using by default a value of `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` for your pool size. This is more or less how a *chunksize* value is computed when you use the `map` or `starmap` methods and you have not specified the *chunksize* argument.

**Using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
from queue import Empty

def init_pool_processes(q):
    global queue

    queue = q

def handle_task(arg):
    results = []
    # Add some number of results to the results list:
    queue.put(arg + arg) # Referencing the global queue
    queue.put(arg * arg)

def main(tasks):
    queue = Queue()
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(queue,)) as pool:
        pool.map(handle_task, tasks)
        try:
            while True:
                value = queue.get_nowait()
                print(value)
        except Empty:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([7, 2, 3])
```

Although callling `queue.empty()` is not supposed to be reliable for a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, as long as you are doing this after all the tasks have finished processing, it seems no more unreliable than relying on blocking get calls raising an exception only after all items have been retrieved:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

def init_pool_processes(q):
    global queue

    queue = q

def handle_task(arg):
    results = []
    # Add some number of results to the results list:
    queue.put(arg + arg) # Referencing the global queue
    queue.put(arg * arg)

def main(tasks):
    queue = Queue()
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(queue,)) as pool:
        pool.map(handle_task, tasks)
        while not queue.empty():
            value = queue.get_nowait()
            print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([7, 2, 3])
```

But if you want to do everything strictly according to what the documentation implies is the only reliable method when using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, that would be by using sentinels as you already are doing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

class Sentinel:
    pass

SENTINEL = Sentinel()

def init_pool_processes(q):
    global queue

    queue = q

def handle_task(arg):
    results = []
    # Add some number of results to the results list:
    queue.put(arg + arg) # Referencing the global queue
    queue.put(arg * arg)
    queue.put(SENTINEL)

def main(tasks):
    queue = Queue()
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(queue,)) as pool:
        pool.map_async(handle_task, tasks) # Does not block
        sentinel_count = len(tasks)
        while sentinel_count != 0:
            value = queue.get()
            if isinstance(value, Sentinel):
                sentinel_count -= 1
            else:
                print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([7, 2, 3])
```

**Conclusion**

If you need to use a queue for output, I would recommend a `multiprocessing.Queue`. In this case using sentinels is really the only 100% correct way of proceeding. I would also use the `map_async` method so that you can start processing results as they are returned.

**Using a Managed Queue**

This is Pingu's answer, which remains deleted for now:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from random import randint

def process(n, q):
    for x in range(randint(1, 10)):
        q.put((n, x))

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        queue = manager.Queue()
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.starmap(process, [(n, queue) for n in range(5)])
        while not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I was aware of just returning multiple values as a solution.  But then I lose out on concurrency. I can't start working on results until its task is done. My code was only meant to be a simplification to illustrate my question.  Still, the original question remains: Is there an easy way to tell that a Queue is empty and that no more items will be added? Perhaps the answer is "No, you can't."

Comment: Meant to tag you in the previous reply.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, there is a way of telling in your case when a *managed* queue is empty. The answer was provided by @Pingu, whose answer was deleted, but which I will try to undelete.  The solution is: as long as you are only getting items from the queue *after* all tasks have finished, which is your case, then  you don't need to put sentinel values on the queue; you simply do non-blocking get calls on the queue until a `queue.Empty` exception is raised or you can do blocking get calls `while not `queue..empty()`. (More ...)

Comment: But if you follow my recommendation of switching to using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead, testing for `queue.Empty()` is not reliable . But as long as you try to get the results from the queue *before* attempting to terminate the pool (you must always get all the items from a `multiprocessing.Queue` that were placed there by another process before joining or terminating that process) using *non-blocking` gets within the `with` block, then just catch a `queue.Empty` exception. Or, continue doing what you  have been doing using *sentinels*, which is not so terrible.

Comment: I have added three ways of using a `multiprocessing.Queue instance`, but the third way (using sentinels) is the only way that fully conforms to the documentation. I have also added the answer created and deleted by @Pingu, which uses your managed queue, which really does not need to be using sentinels at all since the call to `queue.Empty()` is reliable when it is being done after you know all tasks have completed putting items on the queue.

Comment: You said, "I was aware of just returning multiple values as a solution. But then I lose out on concurrency. I can't start working on results until its task is done." But if you use `starmap` you are blocked until all tasks have finished and you still do not get to work on any results that have been put on the queue until all results have been created. So if that is what you really want to do, then do not use `starmap`; use `imap_unordered` or `map_async` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your expansive answer.  My sample code originally used starmap_async, but I foolishly thought it made no difference, and was trying to simplify as much as possibly.  I should have known better.